# Get id of updated row in Sequelize - MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I want to get id of affected row in update action using **Sequlaize.update** method.

```js
const result = await Voucher.update(
  {
     used: "1",
  },
  {
    where: {
      voucher_group_id: 5,
      used: "0",
    },
    limit: 1,
    returning: true,
  }
);
```

when I set **returning** to **true**, the result was **[null, 1]**. but the affected row id is other value like: **72**

Comment: The `returning` option is only supported in PostGres, not MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

The `returning` option is only for the Postgres dialect, as specified in the Sequelize v6 Documentation for [Model#update](https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/model.js%7Emodel#static-method-update).

If you are using a Dialect like MySQL, you could load in the record you want to update via `Model#findOne` first and then use `instance#update`.

```
const voucher = await Voucher.findOne({
  where: {
    voucher_group_id: 5,
    used: "0"
  }
});

// voucher is potentially null at this point

voucher.update({ used: "1" });
```

Side note: If your `used` field on your Voucher model is a boolean, you can use `true/false` and Sequelize will automatically convert these to the tiny int equivalent values for your dialect.

Comment: Thank you for your help. My concern is that between the findOne and the update , another user will select the voucher code at the same time and the voucher code will be assigned to two people. Is it possible to happen?

Comment: @MajidGhafoorzade Yes this is absolutely possible/a real concern. You can utilize table update locks for this when you grab the record in `Model#findOne`. Here is a link to the documentation in [Sequelize](https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/model.js~model#static-method-findAll) as well as the corresponding [MySQL Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locks-set.html).